# Adding an adjective before a verb?

Tags: grammar, adjectives, song-lyrics

In this lyric "隣で歌う声怖がりな背中を押して" I'm confused how the がりな背中を押して works. I know how 背中を押して is used thanks to [this post](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/36342/%E8%83%8C%E4%B8%AD%E3%82%92%E6%8A%BC%E3%81%99-phrase-meaning). But what does 怖がりな note. Is the person or the action 怖がりな?

Comment: It looks like this is from a song called ニジイロストーリーズ.

Comment: It is from Nijiiro Stories. I translate a lot of Project SEKAI related stuff.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Structurally, 怖がりな must connect to a noun, not a verb. 背中を押して, despite being an idiom, isn't an atomic unit by itself; it consists of a noun 背中 taking the を-marked place of the verb (in te-form) 押して. Thus, 怖がりな modifies 背中.

If we describe the "back" that is being "pushed" (with the understanding that this is an idiom that describes encouraging a person) as "cowardly", it stands to reason that this is really describing (by [metonymy](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/metonymy)) the person who needs encouragement.

Answer (score 2):

怖がりな is the form 怖がりだ takes before the noun it's modifying.

The question then is what is *it*?

*It* is a relative clause, "*who is a timid person*".

怖がり could be either a coward or a timid individual.  I decided, not knowing more context, to take a more optimistic approach (that the person is timid, not cowardly).

So, the lyric is referring to encouraging someone who is timid.